# Does any brain-computer interface model draw on neural temporal codes?

Tags: neuroscience, brain, biomedical-technology

I am studying brain-computer interfaces (BCIs) and neural encoding/decoding for a class. Most decoding algorithms that I have encountered for BCIs tackling movement problems seem to assume a neural rate code (having done my research on this, I include [this](https://doi.org/10.1016/B978-0-12-375027-3.00007-7) link, a chapter by Yu and others, where the model on pp. 226, among others, assume that all the information necessary to decode neural activity is the number of spikes in a given time period, as would be the case if the neurons were using a rate code).

My question: does any BCI decoding algorithm (for movement) assume that neurons follow a temporal code?

Comment: Have you found BCI decoding algorithms based on machine learning? As those algorithms should be "model free" would be a nice approach to check the relative importance of rate v/s spike coding in the brain.